# How do I remove rows whose columns are the same but not in the same order?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
+--+----+----+
|ID|Col1|Col2|
+--+----+----+
|0 |ABC |DEF |
+--+----+----+
|1 |ABC |XYZ |
+--+----+----+
|2 |XYZ |ABC |
+--+----+----+
|3 |DEF |XYZ |
+--+----+----+
```

I want to write a query that will remove any rows which have entries all of which are contained in another row, *although not necessarily in the same order*. So in this case I would want to remove row 2 because it contains the same entries as row 1. The output should therefore be:

```
+--+----+----+
|ID|Col1|Col2|
+--+----+----+
|0 |ABC |DEF |
+--+----+----+
|1 |ABC |XYZ |
+--+----+----+
|3 |DEF |XYZ |
+--+----+----+
```

Can some variation of `DISTINCT` achieve this?

Here's my (failed) attempt so far to identify any cross-similarities that wouldn't be picked up by a normal `DISTINCT`:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM myTable a JOIN myTable b ON a.Col1 = b.Col1 WHERE a.Col1 = b.Col2 AND a.Col2 = b.Col1
)
```

Comment: DISTINCT will not help, because you need some (heavy) string comparisons to perform, i.e. for "XYZ" in Col1 you need to find all "XYZ", "XZY", "YXZ", "YZX", "ZXY", "ZYX" in Col2.  Not a good idea to do such in SQL. Not sure its even possible tbh.

Comment: As an aside - after you've mopped the floor, remember to fix the leak. If you want to prevent this from recurring in the future, you can apply some form of constraint here - either a check constraint on the table that ensures that Col1 < Col2 and a unique index or an indexed view that swaps the columns if necessary and again has the unique index.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am trying to do this but haven't been successful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174806/how-to-select-into-with-a-check-on-each-row-before-insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *ID* in your table is **UNIQUE**..

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (id) IN
(SELECT B.id FROM
myTable A, myTable B
WHERE A.col1 = B.col2
  AND A.col2 = B.col1)
```