# How to SELECT INTO with a check on each row before insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a table using `SELECT INTO` but want to avoid creating rows where two of the columns are equal but in different order to two other columns. For example, say I have a query that generates the following data

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|A   |XYZ |
+----+----+
|2   |4   |
+----+----+
|WA  |AB  |
+----+----+
|W   |B   |
+----+----+
|XYZ |A   |
+----+----+
```

In this case I would want to add all rows except for the last, because it is a flipped duplicate of the first row. Here is a conceptual version of what I've got at the moment:

```
SELECT
    a.col1 AS col1,
    b.col1 AS col2,
INTO newTable
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON -- some match criteria
-- If I were to end the query here, it would generate the table shown above

-- my attempt at avoiding cross duplicates:
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT x.col1,x.col2
    FROM -- what name do I use here? AS x
    WHERE (x.col1 = col2 AND x.col2 = col1)
)
```

Note that the criteria for generating the code *before* that outer `WHERE` block is quite large, and I would prefer not to have to repeat it within the `NOT EXISTS` block. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried something like `select a.col1, b.col1 [other criteria] except select b.col1, a.col1 [other criteria] into newTable ...`?

Comment: @Dan no I wasn't aware of that, but it sounds like the right direction..

Comment: @Dan that will knock out both rows.  If you want to keep 'A','XYZ' and discard 'XYZ','A', you need to a means to determine the priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN col2 > col1 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END,
  CASE WHEN col2 > col1 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
FROM newTable
```

Comment: What if `col1 < col2`?

Comment: This swaps the col1 and col2 values so they are always in order.  Then it filters duplicate rows.  Since you don't say why you want ('A','XYZ') but not ('XYZ','A'), I'm assuming you don't care.